# How do I pass this regular expression search challenge?

Tags: python, regex

I can't pass this code challenge:

> Regular Expression Search Challenge Using the Python string below to
>   perform a search using a regular expression that you create.
>
> search_string=’’’This is a string to search for a regular expression
>   like regular expression or regular-expression or regular:expression or
>   regular&expression’’’
>
> Write a regular expression that will find all occurrences of: a.
>   regular expression b. regular-expression c. regular:expression d.
>   regular&expression in search_string
>
> Assign the regular expression to a variable named pattern
>
> Using the findall() method from the re package determine if there are
>   occurrences in search_string
>
> Assign the outcome of the findall() method to a variable called match1
>
> If match1 is not None: a. Print to the console the pattern used to
>   perform the match, followed by the word ‘matched’
>
> Otherwise: a. Print to the console the pattern used to perform the
>   match, followed by the words ‘did not match’

Here is my code:

```
import re
#The string to search for the regular expression occurrence (This is provided to the student)

search_string = '''This is a string to search for a regular expression like regular expression or 
regular-expression or regular:expression or regular&expression'''

#1.  Write a regular expression that will find all occurrences of:
#    a.  regular expression
#    b.  regular-expression
#    c.  regular:expression
#    d.  regular&expression
#    in search_string
#2.  Assign the regular expression to a variable named pattern
ex1 = re.search('regular expression', search_string)
ex2 = re.search('regular-expression', search_string)
ex3 = re.search('regular:expression', search_string)
ex4 = re.search('regular&expression', search_string)
pattern = ex1 + ex2 + ex3 + ex4
#1.  Using the findall() method from the re package determine if there are occurrences in search_string
#.   Assign the outcome of the findall() method to a variable called match1
#2.  If match1 is not None:
#    a.  Print to the console the pattern used to perform the match, followed by the word 'matched'
#3.  Otherwise:
#    a.  Print to the console the pattern used to perform the match, followed by the words 'did not match'
match1 = re.findall(pattern, search_string)
if match1 != None:
  print(pattern + 'matched')
else:
  print(pattern + 'did not match')
```

I don't really get any feedback from the program. It just tells me I failed without an error message.

Comment: You're too focused on solving the Challenge, honestly. I'll give you a hint with parts. 1. `re.findall('ONE[\S]TWO', 'ONE&TWO')`, 2. `re.findall('ONE[\S]TWO', 'ONE)TWOTHREE')`, 3. `re.findall('ONE[\S]TWO', 'ONE)TWO----THREE')`, 4. `re.findall('ONE[\S]+TWO', 'ONE@TWO')`, 5. `re.findall('ONE[\S]+TWO', 'ONE>>>>>>TWO')`, 6. `re.findall('ONE[\S]+TWO', 'ONE>>>>>>TWO>>>>>>>THREE')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I run your code I do get an error telling me that

```py
pattern = ex1 + ex2 + ex3 + ex4
```

failed because adding Match objects is not supported.

The challenge is likely attempting to teach you to use [character sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-9) in regular expressions.
Basically, you don't need `ex1`, `ex2`, and so on. You simply need to define the regex pattern in the `pattern` variable and supply it to `re.findall`.

I'd also recommend tools like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for experimenting with regex.

Comment: So I changed my variable to ```pattern = re.findall('regular.expression', search_string) ```which returns the proper matches, but I still can't quite get it. Maybe it's the wording that's throwing me off, but why would I then need to assign the results of the pattern findall function to a new variable called match1?

Comment: I think you misunderstood, my point was that you should set `pattern = 'some-regex-pattern-here'`. Be aware that `.` in RegEx means "any character", so your current pattern will indeed match the examples, but also `regular@expression`, `regularqexpression` and so on, which is also why I pointed you towards character sets.

Answer (score 2):

Hey there I know this is a bit late but I am currently going through these same challenges so I figured I'd lend a hand on how to get past the check point.

So "tfw" is absolutely correct in using the character sets. And its actually just 1 line of code for all of the...

```
#1.  Write a regular expression that will find all occurrences of:
#    a.  regular expression
#    b.  regular-expression
#    c.  regular:expression
#    d.  regular&expression
#    in search_string
#2.  Assign the regular expression to a variable named pattern
```

So basically the easiest way to do this is by specifying the expression with each character set. So it looks something like this...

```
pattern = "regular[ -:&]expression"
```

Doing this allowed us to add the space, the -, the : and the & in the same variable called pattern. Now your second part...

```
#1.  Using the findall() method from the re package determine if there are occurrences in search_string
#.   Assign the outcome of the findall() method to a variable called match1
#2.  If match1 is not None:
#    a.  Print to the console the pattern used to perform the match, followed by the word 'matched'
#3.  Otherwise:
#    a.  Print to the console the pattern used to perform the match, followed by the words 'did not match'
```

You already had the right code for, just needed the right regex to call from. But I'll post it just so no confusion.

```
match1 = re.findall(pattern, search_string)
if match1 != None:
  print(pattern + 'matched')
else:
  print(pattern + 'did not match')
```

Anyways hope this helps anyone else that may need just a little push in the right direction. I always find it easier to see what the code is doing rather than be told how the code should be with little direction :D

Answer (score -1):

Change the expression to `pattern = regular[ -:&]expression`

Comment: It seems duplicated with @RobertB922's answer.